# Is using @CrossOrigin the same as overriding addCorsMapping() in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my controller I currently added the following annotation `@CrossOrigin`:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dev/test")
    @CrossOrigin
    public class MyController {
    ...
    }
```

And also wondering the following implementation in WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private String allowedRequest = "/**";
    private String allowedOrigins = "*";
    private String[] allowedMethods = {"GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"};

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping(allowedRequest).allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .allowedMethods(allowedMethods);
    }
}
```

Are those two options provide the same result? And are there any difference from security standpoint (which one is more secure than the other)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`WebMvcConfigurer#addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry)` creates a global CORS configuration applied to all controllers, and `@CrossOrigin` allows for a more fine-grained control over it. For the case when they are used together, as stated in the javadoc of `@CrossOrigin`:

> The rules for combining global and local configuration are generally additive -- e.g. all global and all local origins. For those attributes where only a single value can be accepted such as allowCredentials and maxAge, the local overrides the global value.